# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'post') - Creating a Laravel Vue page with Inertia.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I'm developing a create page in Laravel with Vue.js using the Inertia.js framework for server-side rendering. However, I'm encountering an error that says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'post')". This error occurs when attempting to submit the form on the page.

Here's a breakdown of my code structure:

**Create Page**

```
<div class="p-6 overflow-hidden bg-white rounded-md shadow-md dark:bg-dark-eval-1">
        <div class="mx-auto max-w-7xl sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div class="overflow-hidden bg-white shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg">
                <div class="p-6 bg-white border-b border-gray-200">
                    <form @submit.prevent="form.post(route('users.store'))">
                        <div class="mb-6">
                            <label
                                for="name"
                                class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300"
                                >Name</label
                            >
                            <input
                                type="text"
                               
                                name="name"
                                class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5"
                                placeholder=""
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-6">
                            <label
                                for="email"
                                class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300"
                                >Email</label
                            >
                            <input
                                type="email"
                               
                                name="email"
                                class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5"
                                placeholder=""
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-6">
                            <label
                                for="password"
                                class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300"
                                >Password</label
                            >
                            <input
                                type="password"
                               
                                name="password"
                                class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5"
                                placeholder=""
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-6">
                            <label
                                for="password_confirmation"
                                class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300"
                                >Confirm Password</label
                            >
                            <input
                                type="password"
                               
                                name="password_confirmation"
                                class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5"
                                placeholder=""
                            />
                        </div>


                    <BreezeButton
                  class="bg-blue-600 mr-2"
                ><button type="submit">Save User</button>
                  
                </BreezeButton>
                       
                 <BreezeButton
                  class="bg-gray-600 mr-2"
                ><Link :href="route('users.index')">Cancel</Link>
                  
                </BreezeButton>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
import {Link, useForm} from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3"

export default {
components : {
    Link
},
setup(){
    const form = useForm({
        name: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
    })

    return { form }
}
```

}

**User Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request){

  
       $users=User::create([
           'name' => $request->name,
           'email' => $request->email,
           'password' => $request->password,
       ]);
  
       return redirect()->route('users.index')
                       ->with('success','User created successfully.');
    }
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('/store', [UserController::class, 'store'])->name('users.store');
```

Comment: where is the "form.post(...)" coming from? did you use `useForm?`

Comment: Yes, I use the useForm. Edited the code to add the <script>

Answer (score 0):

If you are using setup you do like my code for better user formatting

First you cannot access `route()` inside a `.vue` file it only accessible via `.blade` extension.

Second separate your function from your template.

```js
<template>
...
<form @submit.prevent="submit">
...
</form>
...
</template>
<script setup>
import {Link, useForm} from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3"

const form = useForm({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
})

const submit = () => form.post('/store')

</script>
```

Comment: there is an error: error 404. How can i solve it?

Comment: If you setup your `inertia` app using `laravel/breeze` you can use `route()` method since it is from the `tighten/ziggy` package that is included in the stack

Comment: try debugging the route by using `php artisan route:list` it will tell you the correct route and change the path of `form.post`

Comment: @Japs I'm also like that at first